# Trouble with min/max/inflection points

Tags: calculus, functions

I've learnt that in order to find mix/max points, you find the $x$ values where the first derivative is equal to zero and then plug in the $x$ values into $f''\left(x\right)$ to see what it is (positive for min or negative for max). This works, but if $f''\left(x\right)$ is zero, it could be a min/max/inflection point ( take $f''\left(x^3\right)$ and $f''\left(x^4\right)$ ), so from here I would find the value of f(x) on both sides of the x value (e.g $± 0.1$ of it) and then find the answer.

The last step of finding  $±0.1$ of the $x$ value didn't seem very robust, for example, take the equation $f\left(x\right)=x^5+x\cos \left(\frac1{x^2+0.01}\right)$, where this wouldn't work as the function fluctuates very rapidly around $x=0$, so how would I go about a problem like this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is instructive to remember that there is a max/min if and only if the f'(x) changes signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that just taking $\pm 0{.}1$ is not robust. What is really happening here? You are trying to determine the sign of the first derivative. If you have $f'(x_0)$ and the sign of the first derivative changes at $x_0$, then you will have

- a local maximum, if it is a change from $+$ to $-$
- a local minimum, if it is a change from $-$ to $+$.

A very informal way of seeing that: if the first derivative changes from $-$ to $+$, it means that the graph of $f$ will first be going down and then going up, so you will get a v-shape which resembles a local minimum. Same goes for a change from $+$ to $-$. So instead of just taking the value at $x_0\pm 0{.}1$, you have to solve the inequalities $f'(x)>0$ and $f'(x)<0$ (which I don't feel like doing for the function you proposed right now, from the top of my hat I don't see a nice way of getting to a result).